# How to delete files, symbolic in one folder, but leave its subdirectories unchanged?

Tags: find, rm, patterns

Assume there is a folder that has files, symbolic links, and subdirectories as following:

```
files: file1, file2, file3, file4
symbolic links: link1-->file2, link2-->file3
subdirectories: dir1, dir2
```

I want delete file1, file3, file3, file4, link1, and link2. But leave dir1 and dir2 unchanged.

Note that, there is no one pattern such as `file*` can cover all files' name. The name of files above are just for example and actually their name are various.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `find` with a `type` argument.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```

You can do a dry run by removing the `-exex rm -f {} \;` portion to see the files that would be deleted.

Comment: Quite enough `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete`

Comment: @Costas that's a Gnu switch only...

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm -f {} +`

Comment: I edit the question to add symbolic links to be considered. Because I also find there exist some symbolic links in my folder.

Comment: @jasonwryan, `-maxdepth` is the GNU extension. `-delete` comes from BSDs. `-maxdepth` is also found in some other implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is to use

```
$ rm ./*
```

Here we are not using recursive delete (`-r`) and so only the files (except the hidden ones) in the parent directory should get deleted.

Comment: I'd offer supress error output `rm * 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Note that it will delete symlinks, including symlinks to directories.

Comment: `rm *` will not delete hidden files, as `*` doesn't expand hidden files. Symlinks was not mentioned in question and if present it will be deleted along with and other file types leaving directories and their content.

Comment: `rm *` is wrong unless you can guarantee none of the file names will start with `-` in any context that command line will be used, which in a Q&A site answer is not the case. You want `rm -- *` or `rm ./*`.

Comment: Yes that should be a fail-safe way. Thanks for pointing it out  :)

Answer (score 1):

Using bash (and ignoring symlinks):

```
for file in *; do [[ -f $file ]] && rm -- "$file"; done
```

Comment: `[[ -f $file ]]` also returns true for symlinks to regular files (symlinks for which you can determine the type of the target is "regular"). You need either `for file in ./*` or `rm -- "$file"` here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks: I had tested it but didn't pick that up. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
rm -- *(.)
```

removes the *regular* files only

```
rm -- *(D.)
```

to also include dot-files (hidden ones)

```
rm -- *(D^/)
```

removes all types of files except directories (that include symlinks to directories)

```
rm -- *(D^-/)
```

removes all types of files except directories and symlinks to directories (it would remove symlinks to directories if it can't determine the type of the target of the symlink though).

The GNU `find` equivalent of that latter one would be:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -xtype d -delete
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo mkdir a b c d e

sudo touch a/1 b/2 c/3 d/4 e/5 e/a e/b   
ls                  
a  b  c  d  e  pqr  xyz

cd a/         
ls   
1

cd ../e/     
ls      
5 a b

cd /var/warehouse/abc/  
find . -type f ! -path "./a*" ! -path "./b*"        
./d/4   
./e/a   
./e/b   
./e/5   
./c/3

sudo find . -type f ! -path "./a*" ! -path "./b*" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: This removes files in subdirectories as well.

Comment: @MichałGórny: yeah, exactly.

Comment: If you are going to remove my formatting edit, at least replace it with a similarly formatted one: you current version is unreadable...

Comment: @jasonwryan : I am trying out the same